# How do I run a docker instance from a DockerFile?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I finally figured out how to get docker up and running.

```
docker run --name my-forum-nodebb --link my-forum-redis:redis -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 4567:4567 -P -t -i nodebb/docker:ubuntu
```

I linked it to a redis instance, cool.

This is from scratch and I assume that when I created the redis instance

```
docker run --name my-forum-redis -d -p 6379:6379 nodebb/docker:ubuntu-redis
```

it pulls the image from a remote repo?

NodeBB offers a `Dockerfile` https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB/blob/master/Dockerfile I am not really quite sure how to use it. I am assuming that I can somehow create a local environment by calling this Dockerfile on my remote.

Is this correct? If so how can I create the local instance pointing to the remote?

Comment: you can build the docker image in your local environment and pull it locally

Comment: $ cat Dockerfile | docker build -t <image_name> -  # mind the hyphen

Comment: @jbobbylopez try escaping your `code in comments` -

Answer (score 373, accepted):

## Download `Dockerfile` and Build a Docker Image

Download the `Dockerfile` to a directory on your machine, and from that same directory, run the following [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) command. Make sure to replace `image_name` with what you would like to name your image. [Docker image naming restrictions can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53178517/4709300)

```bash
docker build --tag 'image_name' .
```

This will give you an image on your local machine that you can create a container from. To do so, you'll need to run the following [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command. Make sure to replace `image_name` with what you named your image in the previous command.

```bash
docker run --detach 'image_name'
```

Comment: How does this work? If I just simply have the dockerfile how does it know about my project? Is there a link in the dockerfile? Then I assume if there is docker handles packaging a new image that I can then migrate over to my server. In this packaging it absorbs all the assets of my project? Sorry if I sound ignorant, docker is a new concept to me but I am enjoying learning.

Comment: Thanks by the way and what does the <> represent in your example why did you choose <nodebb>?

Comment: No docker container knows about "your" project, they are very generic.

Comment: This is answering a lot of my questions though https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry dont enter the parameter <nodebb> verbatim. It's a placeholder to specify your own tag name eg 'docker build -t mytag .'

Answer (score 134):

While other answers were usable, this really helped me, so I am putting it also here.

From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files):

> Instead of specifying a context, you can pass a single Dockerfile in
> the URL or pipe the file in via STDIN. To pipe a Dockerfile from
> STDIN:

```
$ docker build - < Dockerfile
```

> With Powershell you can run:

```
Get-Content Dockerfile | docker build -
```

When the build is done, run command:

```
docker image ls
```

You will see something like this:

```
REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                     <none>              123456789        39 seconds ago      422MB
```

Copy your actual IMAGE ID and then run

```
docker run 123456789
```

Where the number at the end is the actual Image ID from previous step

If you do not want to remember the image id, you can tag your image by

```
docker tag 123456789 pavel/pavel-build
```

Which will tag your image as `pavel/pavel-build`

Comment: Amazing that in 2020 that first snippet took so long to find.

Comment: This is just the accepted answer with more ceremony.

Comment: the doc is only the source of truth can the tool provide.

Comment: This is the only answer, that has to be accepted.

Comment: such answers makes you hit upvote

Comment: If you pipe from stdin your `COPY` commands may not work as expected. Consider `docker build -f ./path/to/Dockerfile`

Answer (score 93):

You cannot start a container from a Dockerfile.

The process goes like this:

> Dockerfile **=[`docker build`]=>** Docker image **=[`docker run`]=>** Docker container

To start (or run) a container you need an image. To create an image you need to build the Dockerfile[1].

[1]: you can also `docker import` an image from a tarball or again `docker load`.

Answer (score 84):

Straightforward and easy solution is:

```
docker build .
=> ....
=> Successfully built a3e628814c67
docker run -p 3000:3000 a3e628814c67
```

`3000` - can be any port

`a3e628814c68` - hash result given by success build command

**NOTE**: you should be within directory that contains **Dockerfile**.

Comment: Don't miss that tiny little dot `.`  though , `docker build .`

Answer (score 22):

The title is what brought me here, this runs a container from a Dockerfile directly.

```
docker build --no-cache . |  grep "Successfully built" | sed 's/Successfully built //g' | xargs -I{} docker run {}
```

Answer (score 16):

```bash
docker run $(docker build -q .)
```

Comment: I needed to add --load (or --push) `docker run $(docker build --load -q .)` and for fish: `docker run (docker build --load -q .)`

Answer (score 8):

With docker desktop 20.10.8

You can use a docker-compose file to name and configure your environment.

```
services:
    my_instance:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: my_instance.dockerfile
```

Then `docker compose up` or `docker compose run /bin/bash` or whatever.

per https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#dockerfile

Answer (score 4):

[image]

We can see the docker file is inside the project folder `E:\Code SAmple\flutqr`

**build command**

```
docker build -t fluweb .
```

- `fluweb` is the name for image you can specify any name
- `.` represent current directory

Look at your docker desktop you can see your published images instead rickandmorty(i edited fluweb).
[image]

if you want re run that image you can use
That run button .else

[image]
You can use this command

```
docker run rickandmorty
```

Now it live

[image]

Comment: hi there ! <3 Flutter web. When you run this, we are creating the image correct? I'm confused on how to mount and run this image now