# docker - Restrictions regarding naming image

Tags: image, docker

I have questions regarding restrictions about naming images. I search online and saw different issue and answers.

which special characters are not allowed in docker image name? (e.g. '*', '$', ',', '_' ...)
Is it possible to use uppercase char for image name?

Answer (score 15):

This documentation describes the rules for the docker image name and tag:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description

> Name components may contain lowercase letters, digits and separators.
>   A separator is defined as a period, one or two underscores, or one or
>   more dashes. A name component may not start or end with a separator.
>
> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase
>   letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not
>   start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128
>   characters.

Answer (score 13):

From https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/reference/regexp.go:

> // nameComponentRegexp restricts registry path component names to start
>   // with at least one letter or number, with following parts able to be
>   // separated by one period, one or two underscore and multiple dashes.

This applies to the image name itself.

- The regex for the letters is all lower case, no upper case letters.
- You can include a hostname and an optional port number after a colon at the very beginning.
- You can include a path between the hostname and image name with slashes `/`, and each element of the path has the same restrictions as the image name itself.
- After the image name, you can append a tag after a colon or a digest after an `@`.

Expressed with the common bracketed notation:

```
[somehost.com[:1234]][/some-path/to/the]image-name[:myTag1.2.3]
[somehost.com[:1234]][/some-path/to/the]image-name[@ca468b84b84846e84...]
```

Comment: Hi, so things like `host.com/a/b/c/d/e:1.0` is acceptable (with extra slashes)? I am afraid of whether some other tools will reject it or fail secretly? Thanks very much (Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513122)