# Can I have extra slash "/" in Docker (and Containerd) image name?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I need to copy images from Docker Hub into a private registry. For example, I need `redislabs/rebloom:2.2.2`. Then, can I name it `my-private-registry.com/my-organization/redislabs/rebloom:2.2.2`? (Notice there is `my-organization` which I *cannot* modify.)

In other words, is `a.com/b/c/d:v1.0` ok or not?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861791/how-are-docker-image-names-parsed) post and see Docker can parse it. However, will some tools reject this? Will Containerd reject this? **I am afraid that they accept it but fails somewhere, which may be very difficult to debug.**

Thank you very much!

Comment: This should not be a problem for docker, most private docker trusted registry (DTR) are setup in this pattern.

Comment: @LeelaPrasad Thanks very much! Could you please provide some links so I can read?

Comment: May not be much, but it might give you an idea on how it looks/works https://www.docker.com/blog/dtr/

Comment: @LeelaPrasad I do see it. But it only says things like `  docker tag alpine:latest <Your DTR hostname>/admin/alpine:latest`. I think `<Your DTR hostname>` is like `hello.com` but NOT like `hello.com/some-organization`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My day job uses image names with a similar structure (hosted on Amazon ECR) and they work fine with plain Docker, Compose, and Kubernetes.  I would not expect to run into any trouble with this, unless the specific image repository has stricter rules.